# IOS: UIImage fileNamed -> Too many files open

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

In my IOS application I have the 5 UIImageViews which load a bunch of images using the [UIImageView fileName:...] API. In IOS 4.2, im getting application crashes because of the following error:

```
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/6CCEFE3D-198A-460A-B496-EA4C11F4200D/EKS.app/e250.png'
     error = 24 (Too many open files)

/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib: open() failed with errno=24
/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib: stat() failed with errno=0")
```

How do I go about properly closing the files which are opened using this API?

Thanks

Comment: You say there are only 5 UIImageViews and a "bunch" of images? Can you post the code on how these images are replaced in the UIImageView? My guess is there's something not deallocating properly when you replace the image.

Comment: I think i have isolated the problem. It has to do with the autorelease pools you have to instantiate when you spawn an NSThread.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `initWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageNamed`. If there too many images `imageNamed` try autorelease the file. I think that's why this warning coming.